# Positioning does not match in array

Tags: java, arrays

I am making a simple snake app using two dimensional array from a document I found on internet. I have passed all the tests from the file **TestAsmt1.java** . However, I am sure I have followed all the instructions given in the PDF document. Did I miss something out? Can anyone help me with this? So I can use **PlayGame.java** properly. Thanks

The problem is that when I move the snake, his head duplicates and moves one step in array - which is not written in the code. Can't pinpoint where is the location [image: image here]

This is what I have done so far

source code - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-oxBFusUIjX9bIqG5HhdCNpmIgTEl6mc

pdf file - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QsyrmDSYhsvaUUkHoTl6jPNsgKfLdWPy

MainApp - **PlayGame.java, TestAsmnt.java**

```
public void moveSnake(String direction){
    Position[] arr = new Position[this.snakeBody.length];       

    Position pos = this.newHeadPosition(direction);
    arr[0] = new Position(pos.getRow(), pos.getCol());

    for (int a = 0; a< this.snakeLength; a++){
        arr[a+1] = new Position(this.snakeBody[a].getRow(), this.snakeBody[a].getCol());            
    }

    for (int a = 0; a< this.snakeLength; a++){
        this.snakeBody[a].setRow(arr[a].getRow());
        this.snakeBody[a].setCol(arr[a].getCol());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

found the bug - I have not renew snakebody array before restoring elements from arr array. updated method below

```
public void moveSnake(String direction){
Position[] arr = new Position[this.snakeBody.length];       

Position pos = this.newHeadPosition(direction);
arr[0] = new Position(pos.getRow(), pos.getCol());

for (int a = 0; a< this.snakeLength; a++){
    arr[a+1] = new Position(this.snakeBody[a].getRow(), this.snakeBody[a].getCol());            
}

this.snakeBody = new Position[arr.length];

for (int a = 0; a< this.snakeLength; a++){
    this.snakeBody[a].setRow(arr[a].getRow());
    this.snakeBody[a].setCol(arr[a].getCol());
}
}
```